# Expiration logic with DateTimeField in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a DateTimeField in a Service model defined like this:

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,blank=True)
```

I want to create some expiration logic in my code so that Services that are older than 2 months expire. In my view, only those services that aren't expired will be displayed.

For example I want to do this in a view:

views.py

```
class display_services:
    services = Service.objects.all()
    valid_services = []
    for service in service
        **If Service is Not Expired***
              valid_services.append(service)
    endfor
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just filter by `pub_date`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class DisplayServices(ListView):
    queryset = Service.objects.filter(pub_date__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=60))

    ...
```

Comment: This would simplify things a lot. If you dont mind me asking, what is _gte?

Comment: It matches when the value of the preceding column is greater than or equal to what is passed in. There are also gt, lt, lte, etc. If one of these answers helps you, please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
import datetime as dt
two_months_ago = dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days=-60)
valid_services = Service.objects.filter(pub_date__gte=two_months_ago)
```